# Conductive or insulated motherboard-standoffs?

Tags: grounding, ground-loop, ground-plane, motherboard, cases

AFAIK it's common practice to mount an ATX motherboard to conductive brass standoffs inside the case. There are even metal traces around the screw holes to provide contact between the screws and the motherboard ground-plane.

> 1. Are these traces just for the screws or are these traces there to provide a path between the motherboard ground-plane and the case?
> 2. What's actually better? Conductive standoffs or insulated standoffs?

Comment: It only matters on radiated emissions outside the box as the high layer counts have adequate controlled impedances and ground planes for performance, but there may be exceptions. Most use insulated standoffs now that I have seen.

Comment: @Marty Brass standoffs are probably the most common. If you want non-conductive then search for "nylon motherboard standoffs".

Comment: use anything you have... 
If you look at the metal rings around the mounting holes, you will see that they are not attached to the circuit traces, but are designed to isolate the motherboard from the standoffs.

Comment: Thanks, but what why would i want conductive and why would i want non-conductive?

Comment: brass is stronger

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, the screws are not making contact with the ground-plane of the motherboard?

Comment: did you check yours?

Comment: I measured 0 ohm between the metal traces (or rings, like you call them) around the screw holes and the GND-pins of the 24-pins ATX power connector. So i was assuming the standoffs were electronically connected to the MOBO ground-plane.

Comment: With the inductance of a standoff vs a square board. the board is lower inductance if both are in parallel then the case has little influence on performance unless an OEM has unique emanation issues then they can enable Spread spectrum jitter on clocks or choose the standoff method that works best for CE/FCC tests

Comment: A modern motherboard will work fine with long or short standoffs, conductive or insulating and in a conductive or insulating case.  I would say that a well designed motherboard would only have mechanical recomendations for the standoffs and be electricly indifferent.  Similar to http://superuser.com/questions/1138512/what-exactly-is-grounded-through-motherboard-standoffs